# Can you provide a TU game $[N,\nu]$ that satisfies $\mathcal{PK}(N,\nu)\neq\mathcal{PN}(N,\nu)$?

Tags: game-theory

Following [this question I posted some days ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878565/how-many-imputations-satisfy-the-following-condition-in-a-super-additive-game), I have been suggested to explore several TU solution concepts, in particular the Prekernel ($\mathcal{PK}$). Unfortunately, this is a TU solution concept I'm not familiar with. For what I've read, the Prekernel coincides with the Prenucleolus ($\mathcal{PN}$) whenever the Prekernel consists of a single imputation, but it is different from the Prenucleolus whenever the Prekernel contains more than one imputation (see [Peleg, 1986](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01769258)). I've been trying to come up with a game $[N,\nu]$ in which $\mathcal{PK}\neq\mathcal{PN}$, but I haven't been able to do so.

Thus, **could anyone please provide a super additive game $[N,\nu]$ (ideally, with $|N|=4$) in which $\mathcal{PK}\neq\mathcal{PN}$?** (please, make explicit the sets $\mathcal{PN}$ and $\mathcal{PK}$).

Thank you all very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a four person game which we quantify through

$v=[0,0,0,0,0,1,1/2,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,2]$

while taking the usual lexicographic order of coalitions. The pre-nucleolus of the game is given by

$\mathcal{PN}(N,v)=\{1,1,1,1\}/2,$

whereas the pre-kernel is a line segment that coincides with the core, and it is given by

$\mathcal{PK}(N,v)=conv(\{\{1,0,1,0\},\{1,3,1,3\}/4\})$.

We get $\mathcal{PK}(N,v)\neq \mathcal{PN}(N,v)$. The solutions are visualized by a small graphic

[image: Pre-Kernel Solution within the Imputation Set]

The green enlarged point is the pre-nucleolus, the blue dot is the Shapley value, the red dot is the pre-kernel element $\{1,3,1,3\}/4$, and the yellow line segment represents the pre-kernel solution as well as the core of the game.

The details of how to compute a pre-kernel element would be beyond the scope of our discussion. Nevertheless, a procedure as well as the theoretical foundation of calculating a pre-kernel element is explained in more details within my book that can be found at

[The Pre-Kernel as a Tractable Solution for Cooperative Games](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783642395482)

or you should have a look at the following link

[Determining the Pre-Nucleolus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108449/finding-the-nucleolus)

that gives at least some idea of how to proceed.

Comment: Excuse me for the stupid question, but for "*usual lexicographic order*", we mean:
$\nu(\emptyset)=0,\nu(\{i\})=0\forall i\in N,\nu(\{1,2\})=1,\nu(\{1,3\})=1/2,\nu(\{1,4\})=1,\nu(\{2,3\})=1,\nu(\{2,4\})=0,\nu(\{3,4\})=1,\nu(\{123\})=1,\nu(\{124\})=1,\nu(\{134\})=1,\nu(\{234\})=1,\nu(\{N\})=2$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Is it possible to find a super additive game in which the Prenucleolus does not lie inside the Prekernel; that is, $\mathcal{PN}\notin\mathcal{PK}$?

Comment: No, that is not possible, since the pre-kernel is never empty for every game, and it contains at least the pre-nucleolus. Thus, we have $\mathcal{PN}(N,v)\subseteq \mathcal{PK}(N,v)$ for all games $v \in \Gamma$. This is due to the fact that the pre-kernel was developed as an auxiliary solution concept to investigate the pre-nucleolus.

Comment: In this respect, I want just mention that the DM-bargaining set -- that contains the pre-kernel -- can never be empty too.